# Suggested improvements to chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

In my admittedly limited experience with DA i am finding that many times the OP would not have to ask the question if they knew how to ask it. The answer would be self evident. (Learning Drupal is like learning to walk on water: you have to find out where the stepping stones are.) Consequently, comments evolve into discussions in an attempt to better define or debug the issue.

Moving discussions to chat is a desirable alternative, but there is no simple method to initiate a room between two users unless  the number of comments triggers an automated invitation, and, more important, I have no way of knowing that a response has been made in chat unless I maintain an active window on the room.

For what it's worth, I think that chat would be better used if we had a simple method to initiate an invitation, and if we had the option of having responses sent to our inbox.

Thoughts?

EDIT:

There seems to be a general misconception about this issue. It is not about privileges, or uncontrolled private messaging.

Prefix the whole issue with "If the privileges are in place ..." and we can eliminate that chestnut.

Currently, if the number of comments reaches a pre-set limit, a message appears to encourage the users to move the discussion to chat. Selecting the option, a room is created for the OP and the Answerer. I would like to see this available much sooner so discussions could be moved out of comments.

Because SE users span the globe, if might not be convenient for the chat to be real time due to differences in time zone. I would also like to see inbox notifications for replies.

I agree that social networking is not a desirable feature for Stack Exchange, and should be resisted. However discussions of issues help to drill down to a root cause, eliminate misunderstandings, and aid in the search for a solution which is what Stack Exchange is about.

Comment: Keep in mind that not every user can use the chat: They can only if [their reputation allows them to chat](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/privileges/chat).

Comment: Yes, but they require even more reputation to leave [Comments Everywhere](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment). And if this was on the parent sie, I would already be wanting to move this to chat:-)

Comment: That's by design - it's how we keep the quality levels so high on Stack Exchange sites :) Sometimes the 1% will suffer for the greater good unfortunately. But if they take the time to check out the community, it becomes a moot point. 50 points, which is what you need to comment, is absolutely trivial to earn, and I don't think it's unreasonable to require that in order for people to participate at that level. Yes, it does create a chicken and egg situation on rare occassions but again, that's just the price we pay for the excellent platform we have here.

Comment: Stack Exchange have staunchly resisted any attempts to add social networking features as it would dilute the intended purpose of the platform. Being able to instigate a chat with anyone, anytime, not necessarily within the context of Q+A, just isn't what these sites are for

Comment: _"However discussions of issues help to drill down to a root cause, eliminate misunderstandings, and aid in the search for a solution which is what Stack Exchange is about"_...absolutely. But that's what questions/answers/comments are for. Chat is something different, it's removed from the Q+A process because it's not related to it. Any further integration could only be seen as social networking really. For the record I'm not disagreeing (I'm not agreeing either), just pointing out the arguments I've seen on Meta.SO over the years

Comment: @Clive - Perhaps 'Chat' is the wrong word. Maybe 'Sidebar' would be better. To me it's not about the subject, but rather the type of discussion. Comments are fine for a clear question:response clarification. But I just spent over 2 hours in real time chat with the OP on an issue where we were brainstorming the problem. The mods would have freaked if that discussion had taken place in comments. I am not looking at new function besides the inbox notification. I am just looking at easier access to a function that already exists. BTW Thank you for your clarifications.

Comment: I do know what you're getting it, and you're right it would be great to facilitate those types of discussions (it's also fantastic that you're prepared to give up that much of your time to help others out, much kudos for that). I just don't know how exactly it would work, or if the devs would be prepared to go in that direction. But let's wait and see what they say, it might take a few days as they're obviously pretty busy, but I'm sure the right person will eventually see this